# Multiple many-to-one to a single table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i have a Product table with two many-to-one references (Title & Description) to a single table named TextRef :

Product:

```
<many-to-one lazy="false" name="Title" class="TextRef" column="TitleRef" fetch="join" cascade="save-update"/>
<many-to-one lazy="false" name="Description" class="TextRef"  column="DescriptionRef" fetch="join" cascade="save-update"/>
```

every TextRef has a one-to-many to TextRefItem table :

```
<bag lazy="false" name="Values" table="TextRefItem" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" fetch="join">
  <key column="TextId"></key>
  <one-to-many class="TextRefItem"/>
</bag>
```

now i want to load all of TextRefItem(s) for Title & Description in one go but NHibernate only create a join with the first reference (Title)

```
SELECT this_.ProductId as ProductId7_2_, this_.CategoryId as CategoryId7_2_, 
this_.DescriptionRef as Descript3_7_2_,
textref2_.TextId as TextId8_0_, values3_.TextId as TextId4_, 
values3_.TextItemId as TextItemId4_, values3_.TextItemId as TextItemId9_1_,values3_.LangId as LangId9_1_,
values3_.Text as Text9_1_, values3_.TextId as TextId9_1_ 
FROM
Product this_
inner join TextRef textref2_ on this_.DescriptionRef=textref2_.TextId
left outer join TextRefItem values3_ on textref2_.TextId=values3_.TextId
WHERE this_.ProductId = 1
```

for the other one(Description) it makes a separate select query

how could i tell NHibernate to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why a separate query is made for the second reference (Description). But it is possible to extend fetching strategies via criterias to load a product with all TextRefs and TextRefItems in one shot:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product))
   .SetFetchMode("Description.Values", FetchMode.Join);

criteria.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ProdId", 1));
var list = criteria.List<Product>();
```

Comment: Thanks, i wanted to make this a default behavior but it seems that's not possible by using mapping files